# How check if object exists in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

My problem is that I would like implement a nice solution, using less arrays inside arrays.

I have n arrays with n objects, each object has two properties: name and type. I would like to know how get objects that are in all arrays repeated.

Here is my code:

```
let arraysNoEmpties = [...res].filter(array => array.length > 0);
let attributes = arraysNoEmpties[0].map(p => {
   return { name: p.name, type: p.type };
});

let items = getAtributeInAllArrays(attributes, arraysNoEmpties);
console.log('items: ', items);


const getAtributeInAllArrays = (properties, list) => {
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        const property = properties[i];
        let numTimes = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j< list.length; j++) {
            const array = list[j];
            let propsOfarray = array.map(atr => atr.name);
            if (propsOfarray.indexOf(property.name) !== -1) {
                numTimes++;
                if (numTimes === list.length) {
                    items.push(property);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    items.sort((a,b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0));
    return items;
};
```

Comment: do you have some data and the wanted result?

Comment: provide the data

Comment: So, you want all the repeated objects? Could you please provide the sample result?

Comment: Thank you so much every body!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your arrays will be similar lengths, or all very small (<~20 elements), you could use something like this. Modify the `predicate` function to specify the criteria for two objects matching. For instance, if you add another element or decide `name` is unique even without `type`.

```js
function commonElements(arrays...) {
  const predicate = (obj1, obj2) => {
    return obj1.name == obj2.name && obj1.type == obj2.type;
  };

  return arrays[0].filter(e1 => !arrays.map(array => array.map(e2 => predicate(e1, e2)).includes(true)).includes(false));
}
```

If you’re likely to have some significantly longer arrays, first select the shortest one to use as the basis of the filter:

```js
function commonElements(arrays...) {
  const predicate = (obj1, obj2) => {
    return obj1.name == obj2.name && obj1.type == obj2.type;
  };

  const lengths = arrays.map(arr => arr.length);
  const shortestArray = arrays[lengths.indexOf(lengths.sort((a, b) => a - b)[0])];

  return shortestArray.filter(e1 => !arrays.map(array => array.map(e2 => predicate(e1, e2)).includes(true)).includes(false));
}
```

The last line of both examples is essentially the same, and looks like this in slightly longer form:

```js
shortestArray.filter(e1 => {
  return !arrays.map(array => {
    return array.map(e2 => {
      return predicate(e1, e2);
    }).includes(true);
  }).includes(false);
});
```

For each element of the filter array, it’s compared against every element in each other array using the `predicate` function. If at least one element matches (`.includes(true)`), that array is mapped to `true`. If every array maps to `true` (`! (...) .includes(false)`), the element is accepted by the `.filter(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to filter each object that isn't found in each array provided.
We can make use of the `some` and `every` functions to achieve this:

```
let arrays = [[{name:"1"}, {name:"2"}], [{name:"1"}]]
let objects = [{name:"1"}, {name:"2"}] // only the first object is found in each array
const objectsInEachArray = objects.filter(o => arrays.every(arr => arr.some(r => r.name == o.name && r.type == o.type)))
```

Lets break that down:

1. To check if an object is contained in an array we can use the `array.some()` function. Here we return a boolean to declare a match or not. In this case I guess you want to check each property. Here you could either do a full equality check (deep or shallow) or, in simple cases like this one just explicitly check each property:

   ```
    arr.some(r => r.name == o.name && r.type == o.type)
   ```
2. Since we have multiple arrays and the requirement is that the object should be found at least once in each of them we must call the every method on the 2 dimensional array:

   ```
    arrays.every(arr => arr.some(r => r.name == o.name && r.type == o.type))))
   ```
3. Since we have multiple objects and want the result to be an array with only matching objects we call filter on the object array.

   ```
    objects.filter(o => arrays.every(arr => arr.some(r => r.name == o.name && r.type == o.type)))))
   ```

`objectsInEachArray` now only contains objects that are found in each second level array from `arrays`

Therefore:

```
console.log(objectsInEachArray) -> [{name: "1"}]
```

Comment: You can get `objects` using `[...new Set([].concat(...arrays))]`, although since you’re checking for objects in *every* array, you could just use `arrays[0]` instead

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean.. `objects` is an unrelated array that should be checked against `arrays`. Its not derived from it.